# Why is split undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

This same code was working earlier no modifications. But for some reason now it says it's undefined.

Comment: Your `movie` object doesn't always have a `release_date` property. Therefore `movie.release_date` will give `undefined`.

Comment: `split` is no `undefined`, `movie.release_date` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the movie property has not been passed in. You can guard against this using [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values).